# Getting the first date from what a user has selected

Tags: swift, nsdate

I have an app where the user selects the days of the week they work, so Monday-Sunday are the options. I need to be able to get the date of the first day that they will be working. So if the current day is Saturday and they select their first day of work is Monday, I need to be able to get the date of that Monday?

Any help grateful.

Comment: Lookup table and a tiny bit of code.

Comment: Can you elaborate please, I don't know what that is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to create an enumeration for the weekdays:

```
extension Date {
    enum Weekday: Int {
        case sunday = 1, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday
    }
}
```

Second create an extension to return the next weekday desired:

```
extension Date {
    var weekday: Int {
        return Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: self)
    }
    func following(_ weekday: Weekday) -> Date {
        // **edit**
        // Check if today weekday and the passed weekday parameter are the same
        if self.weekday == weekday.rawValue {
            // return the start of day for that date
            return Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: self)
        }
        // **end of edit**
        return Calendar.current.nextDate(after: self, matching: DateComponents(weekday: weekday.rawValue), matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!
    }
}
```

Now you can use your method as follow:

```
let now = Date()

now.following(.sunday)    // "Mar 10, 2019 at 12:00 AM"
now.following(.monday)    // "Mar 11, 2019 at 12:00 AM"
now.following(.tuesday)   // "Mar 12, 2019 at 12:00 AM"
now.following(.wednesday) // "Mar 6, 2019 at 12:00 AM"
now.following(.thursday)  // "Mar 7, 2019 at 12:00 AM"
now.following(.friday)    // "Mar 8, 2019 at 12:00 AM"
now.following(.saturday)  // "Mar 9, 2019 at 12:00 AM"
```

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus. To take this further thou, if the current day is Monday and the user taps Monday, I need the next day to be that current Monday, not the following. How would I do that?

Comment: Hi @Leo Dabus, Could you help me with this please, I can't seem to work it out. With what I have asked above ^^^? Thanks

Comment: I dont have my mac with me right now. I will take a look once I get a chance

Comment: @HenryBrown You just need to create an extension to return the Weekday component from the current date and check if the current date and the input parameter are monday and just return the same date if it is true.

Comment: Thank you this is good! Although does this only refer to Monday? as Monday was just an example, I need this to work for every day. So if the user selects the current day, I need that day to be returned not the next one.