# UILocalNotification triggers daily even after setting repeatInterval as weekday

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, uilocalnotification

I am trying to create a local notification for a reminder on a particular days in a week.

This is what I did so far to achieve

```
let calender = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

        notification.userInfo = NSDictionary(objects: [employee.deptID!], forKeys: [“deptID”]) as [NSObject : AnyObject]
        if #available(iOS 8.2, *) {
            notification.alertTitle = employee.Name
        } else {
        }
        notification.alertBody = "Its time to remind you about today’s target"

let dc = calender.components([NSCalendarUnit.Weekday , NSCalendarUnit.Hour , NSCalendarUnit.Minute, NSCalendarUnit.Second], fromDate: timePicker.date)
                dc.weekday =  4
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Weekday // TODO :
                notification.fireDate = calender.dateFromComponents(dc)
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

But, the above code is triggering daily at that particular time. I want the notification to trigger at a particular time on the particular weekday.

What is the mistake in the above code ?

Comment: You probably forgot to remove a previously schedule notification

Comment: No.. I even uninstalled the app. Cleared all the notifications.

Comment: So you are stating that you removed all schedule notification and you kept receiving it daily?

Comment: btw you need to set the notification timeZone property to current timezone

Comment: Nooo.. here my question is, even if I set the repeatInterval as `NSCalendarUnit.Weekday` and `weekday =  4` for `UILocalNotification` , I am getting the notification daily. Whats wrong with the above code ?

Comment: You need to get the next date (  next wednesday), create a new date using dateBySettingHour

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33269982/2303865

Comment: Noo.. but to repeat it every week on the particular day of the week, we will be using `repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Weekday` right ? Then why its not working ?

Comment: Also, `timeZone` did not help me. Still it triggers daily

Comment: OP, did you ever get this figured out? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @bkwebhero.. I tried all the solutions. Nothing is working here

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Weekday
```

to

```
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear
```

Comment: Hi, this is not even triggering. I want the notification to trigger every wednesday at that particular time.